# Python: How to apply TTEST_IND to multiple columns and multiple variants in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, t-test, pandas-apply

Need a quick way to apply a t-test to multiple groups and multiple variables. Let's assume I have a table like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': 'a a b b'.split(), 'B': [1,2,3,4], 'C': [4,6, 5,10]})
print(df)
```

The group column has a control and variant. a = control, b = variants

Column B is a metric. Column C is another metric and I have many more metrics. I need to loop through N columns.

I want to group by my 'group' column so I'm always comparing my control to one of the variants in column B and apply the `ttest_ind` function.

Is there a solution with for loops or .apply() ? Ideally, I'd just like to do something like:

```
df.groupby('group').apply(ttest_ind(control, n columns)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
from scipy import stats
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x : stats.ttest_ind(x['B'],x['C']))
Out[96]: 
group
a    (-3.1304951684997055, 0.08867762313423291)
b     (-1.5689290811054724, 0.2572186472917924)
dtype: object
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Column B is a metric and column C is another metric. The reason why I wanted to group by column 'Group' was because it contains a control which is 'A', variants are 'B'. Also, my real data set has more than just C columns. I need to loop through all the n columns.